# Facebook Unity Webplayer

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I have some problems with my game.
It works fine in any browsers directly: https://unnyhog.com/public/upload/web_unny2/web_unny2.html

But when I'm trying to launch it as facebook app, I get a problem : https://apps.facebook.com/unnyworld_test/

It works fine only on my computer and only in Firefox. Everywhere else nothing happens, even unity web player didn't start at all. Just blank white page or webplayer progress bar with 0%.

These are my canvas settings:

[image]

Did anyone have such problems?

Comment: This is my canvas settings : https://www.monosnap.com/image/oZrX4sn3LyJW3oHL1kl7OKVXJLlYft

Comment: I've solved that problem. I'm currently using self-signed sertificate on my web-site for https requests. Facebook didn't like it. Try Parse.com if you have the same problem.